# How to tell a Python script to close after running

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm a complete beginner in python... I wrote a simple script that pulls some data from a website and saves it to a text file, but after running the script it just sits there and doesn't "terminate". Since I'll be running it as a windows task I need it close on its own after running. Is there a way to tell python to close the terminal after the script finishes? I've looked everywhere and it seems that most people are trying to do the opposite, keep it open after the code runs.
Not sure if it matters but I'm just running the .py file, not in VS or PyCharm. Thanks in advance.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from datetime import date




driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("MyURL")
time.sleep(11)
first = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/div/span[1]')
second = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/span[1]')
third = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/span[1]')

first = first.text
second = second.text
third = third.text

print(first, second, third)

today = date.today()
today1 = today.strftime('%b %d %Y')

list = (today1, first, second, third)
print(list)

file = open('test.txt', 'a')
file.write(today1)
file.write(' ')
file.write(first)
file.write(' ')
file.write(second)
file.write(' ')
file.write(third)
file.write('\n')
file.close()


driver.close()
```

Comment: When you say "running the .py" file, do you mean you double-click it from the Windows Explorer and it gets run? This probably means you have the 'pylauncher' running it, and that would be keeping the window open - but it really depends on what program is configured on your computer to run .py files. Your code doesn't appear to be at fault - it terminates and from there it can do nothing to close the window.

Comment: I don't know why the terminal would stay open, but you can call `exit()` to terminate the script.

Comment: Is it a terminal or the chrome browser that stays open?

Comment: or rename it from `.py` to `.pyd`

Comment: have you tried running it as a windows task? The terminal window may be there only because of how you ran it in the GUI.

Comment: @Grismar correct. I just double click the .py and it runs with Python launcher. I even tried making it an .exe with pyinstaller and still the same behavior.

Comment: @Mike67 no luck.

Comment: @tdelaney Let me try that.

Comment: I was curious and tried: it's not the standard behaviour for the pylauncher, which closes the window unless the script is still running and waiting for input or some other condition to terminate. Have you tried a print statement at the end of the script, to see if the end is reached?

Comment: Yep, It went all the way....I think the issue is the Selenium webdriver... I removed that part of the code and the script closes after running... I think for the time being I might just create a second cmd task to close this one. In the meantime I'll take a look at the answer post and try to make it work. I'll report back If I get something working. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found something that worked. I noticed that the chromedriver process was still running even after the line `driver.close()` executed. I went ahead and killed the process and the script closed immediately. I guess `driver.close()` closes the chrome window but didn't kill chromedriver so the script was hanging waiting for the process to quit. I replaced `driver.close()` with `driver.quit()` and now the script closes after running. Thanks everyone for the help!!

Answer (score 2):

For 1. you need to send your running process to the background and remove the associated job from current shell.

Press `Ctrl`+`Z` and type `bg` to send the installation process to the backgroud
then type `disown`.

You can now close the terminal, the process will still be alive. You can open another terminal and check its process id with `ps -aef`

In my case the process id is `14426`. Unfortunately there's no easy way to reattach it to another terminal (See How to attach terminal to detached process?) unless you used something based on `screen`.

For 2. You can use the following command:

`while kill -0 14426 >/dev/null 2>&1; do sleep 5 ; done ; echo "ok"`
It will print `ok` when the process is over from an other terminal. You can of course change this `echo` command with something more complex.

Source: [BASH: launch background process and check when it ends](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76717/launch-a-background-process-and-check-when-it-ends)

Comment: Since the script exits at the end anyway I don't see how this will help.